# List all combinations of a list of lists where no two elements are the same

Tags: python, list

For Example:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2], [1, 2, 3], [5, 6]]
```

Will generate:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 6], [3, 2, 1, 5], [3, 2, 1, 6]]
```

Any lists containing 2 of the same elements are not allowed: i.e [2, 2, 3, 5]

I've tried using `itertools.product(*list)` to generate a list of all possible combinations and then looking through that list for any lists with duplicates in it, but this is far too cost intensive for my purposes. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: It’s not clear to me what your criteria are for generating lists. Could you post your inefficient solution, just so we can see more clearly what it is you’re trying to do?

Comment: Why not also `[2,3,1,5]` or `[3,1,2,6]`?

Comment: The lists must be generated in order i.e you pick an element from the first list, then the second, and so on. (so maybe itertools was a bad idea :D)

Comment: pick 3 from [1, 2, 3, 5] then 2 from [2], then 1 from [1, 2, 3] then 5 from [5, 6], sorry if im being a little unclear.

Comment: But you *have* to pick an element from each list? And you are sure that that will always be possible?

Comment: Yes, the domain in my implementation for every list will be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] or just a single number i.e [1] from 1-9, and the length of list will always be 9 (9 lists inside)

Comment: So a list like `[[1,2], [1], [2]]` can never happen?

Comment: No that will not be possible. An element will either be a list containing the numbers one to nine, or list containing a single number from one to nine, and there will always be nine elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
In [34]: var = [[1, 2, 3], [2], [1, 2, 3], [5, 6]]

In [35]: [i for i in itertools.product(*var) if len(i) == len(set(i))]
Out[35]: [(1, 2, 3, 5), (1, 2, 3, 6), (3, 2, 1, 5), (3, 2, 1, 6)]

In [36]: var = [[1,2,3,4], [5]]

In [37]: [i for i in itertools.product(*var) if len(i) == len(set(i))]
Out[37]: [(1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 5)]
```

Comment: At first glance this seems to work very well, Thanks, I'll test it out more and get back to you. Very clever.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the formula for `product` found in the [itertools docs](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and just add a tweak:

```
def alt_product(*args, repeat=1):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool if y not in x] #tweak
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

demo:

```
li = [[1, 2, 3], [2], [1, 2, 3], [5, 6]]

list(alt_product(*li))
Out[35]: [(1, 2, 3, 5), (1, 2, 3, 6), (3, 2, 1, 5), (3, 2, 1, 6)]
```

This is likely to be much friendlier on memory since it does not build a list of all combinations and then filter; instead it filters as it goes.